# Pulling random non-recurring image from folder and assigning it to the html tag

Tags: php

I'm working on a website with an image grid with infinite scrolling. For an image grid I'm using [Final Tiles Grid Gallery](http://codecanyon.net/item/final-tiles-grid-gallery/4734090) plugin, which has an infinite scrolling feature and works as follows:
It requires PHP file with html structure of elements that should be added when users reaches certain part of the web page

Part of get-images.php:

```
<div class="tile">
<a class="tile-inner" href="photos/1.jpg">
    <img class="item" src="images/3235535.jpg" />
</a>
```

Now, when certain part of page is reached the plugin calls ajax function to add more pictures. What I'm trying to achieve is automating the process of adding the code to the PHP file. I have too many images to add them all manually. I have very little knowledge in PHP and I found this little piece of code on stackoverflow to help me out:

```
<?php

$dir = "images/";
$images = scandir($dir);
$i = rand(2, sizeof($images)-1);
?>

<img src="images/<?php echo $images[$i]; ?>" alt="" />
```

Now, how do I combine those to achieve my goal? Also, I am planning to append the link to every picture added and the link should correspond with the name of the image (For example the name of image is "12345", then the link should be "abc.com/12345." I know I am asking too much and the second part of my question is completely on me to figure out but I will appreciate any help. Thanks.

Comment: you wish to select random images for grid via Ajax? need code example?

Comment: I don't want to change the way my jquery plugin is working. Since it requires the php file with the code of elements that should be added, I just want to modify this php file the way that it will select random pictures from the folder with batches of 20 untill all of them will be added. Not sure if I explained it clear enough

Comment: Those tools will totally work, but I think you are asking us to help you get started?  First step, create a simple web site, throw three or four images in there and add links to the images. step #1, do it in HTML.  Step #2, do the same site in php but with a tool that you write that grabs four images at random, one time when posted.  Step #3 integrate the plugin but just do one image on the screen at a time (ten seconds?) step 4 = four images. step 5, complete multiple grid attempt.   Start small...

Comment: Well I have it all coded already as I mentioned. The last thing I need to do is modify the php file because I have thousands of images and just want to automate the process a little bit.

Comment: Its not clear on if this is a one time modification or if you intend to upload thousands of images a day, and want to run the script each and every time someone visits your web site. If its a one time deal, you need to take that array output of image filenames and stick it into a file on your server / local host.  But I'm pretty sure you already know that.  What are you asking for?

Comment: I just want to be able to upload images to my folder and not be worrying about modifying the php code every time, that's the ultimate goal

Comment: or use an old windows box, open up a command line interpreter (CLI) (CMD / Dos window?) CD (change directories ) over to the image directory on your local hard drive and type "dir > filenames.txt'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try it:

```
<?php
$count = 20;
function fetch_rand()
{
    $images = glob('images/*.*');
    $rand = array_rand($images);
    return $images[$rand];
}

$my_list = array();
$i = 0;
while($i<$count)
{
    $select = fetch_rand();
    if(!in_array($select,$my_list))
    {
        array_push($my_list,$select);
        $i++;
    }
}

//print_r($my_list); //just for check

foreach($my_list as $image)
{
    $image_link = explode('.',end(explode('/',$image)));
    $image_link = $image_link[0];
    //echo $image_link; //just for check
    ?>
    <div class="tile">
    <a class="tile-inner" href="abc.com/<?php echo $image_link; ?>">
        <img class="item" src="<?php echo $image; ?>" />
    </a>
    </div>
    <?php
}
?>
```

it will select random file from your image directory and never show duplicated.

Note: change `$count` value to your prefer value and image directory address in `fetch_rand` function.